# Revise Dangling Phrase Modifier

Tags: dangling-modifier

How do you rewrite this sentence to improve the dangling modifier and still sound natural.

> *After announcing his candidacy, the residents promised to support the official.*

Comment: After announcing his candidacy, the official was promised the residents' support. (or ...support by the residents.)

Comment: Or 'After he had announced his candidacy...'

Comment: thank you 

Answer (score 1):

Dangling modifier:
After announcing his candidacy, the residents promised to support the official.

It is quite simple to get rid of the dangling modifier:

**After announcing his candidacy, the official** received a promise of support from (the) residents.

The modifier must precede what it modifies: here that is the word official.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using the passive voice as one of the other answers suggests, unless you have a good reason to use it.

Instead, prefer active language:

**The residents promised to support the official *after he announced his candidacy*.**

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to answer this question because the placement of the modifier makes the sentence ambiguous.

If it is uncertain whether the official will announce his candidacy and the promise of support is contingent upon that announcement, then grammar and clarity are improved with:

> The residents promised to support the official if and when he announced his candidacy

If on the other hand, the official has already announced his candidacy, and the residents promised their support after having learned of that announcement, then grammar and clarity are improved with:

> Having learned of his candidacy, the residents promised the official their support.

Frequently, bad grammar reflects unclear meaning.

Comment: thank you sir 